# Múltiples consultas con CrudRepository JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, crud

Tengo que comprobar que los datos que hay en diferentes tablas están validados, para ello estoy realizando consultas 1x1, lo que me preocupa el rendimiento y el alto número de peticiones, ya que van a ser más de 20 tablas.

Estoy usando SpringBoot como framework y en su parte del repository estoy extendiendo de CrudRepository.

```
extends CrudRepository<MiClase, String> {   
 MiClase findByIdAndProcessAndValidated(String id, String process,int validated);
```

Como se puede ver, voy a realizar una consulta a la tabla "x" para buscar un registro en concreto que este validado.

Para ello en la implementación:

```
    Miclase obj1= this.mlRepository
            .findByIdAndProcessAndValidated("1a", "proces1", 1);
    if (obj1!= null) { 
        //Esta validado
        Miclase obj2 = this.mlRepository
                .findByIdAndProcessAndValidated("2b", "proces2", 1);
        if(obj2 != null) {
            ... y así con 20 tablas
        }
    }
```

Mi idea era simplificarlo en:

```
        REPOSITORY:
        List<Miclase> findByIdAndProcessAndValidated(String id, List<String> process, int validated);

        IMPL:
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("proces1");
        lista.add("proces2");
        lista.add("proces3");
        List<MiClase> objs = this.mlRepository
                .findByIdAndProcessAndValidated("cualquierId", lista, 1);
        if(objs != null && objs.size() < 3) {
            Faltan datos en tablas por validar
        }

        PD: Lo importante es la **lista** de procesos, no de Id.
```

El error que obtengo es:

```
06-02-2020 10:13:36.125 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
06-02-2020 10:13:37.247 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
06-02-2020 10:13:37.257 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: el operador no existe: character varying = record
  Hint: Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos.
  Position: 631
```

Al tratarse de un array he visto ejemplos en google de gente que hace: 'In' para decir que está dentro de ese array:

findByIdAnd**In**ProcessAndValidated

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property inIdProcess found for type MiClase! Did you mean 'idProcess'?
```

PD: No está permitido el uso de @Query para "Select ... " ya que el desarrollo puede verse afectado a una base de datos no relacional.

Comment: Lo que sucede es estas utilizando incorrectamente la clausula IN, puedes colocar el código del nuevo método en CrudRepository.

Comment: findByIdAndInProcessAndValidated

Answer (score 1):

Al final era poner el "In" al final de la condidición, entonces también hay que mover las condiciones, el código final queda:

```
Repo:
extends CrudRepository<MiClase, String> {   
 MiClase findByIdAndValidatedAndProcessIn(String id,int validated, List<String> process);

Impl:
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("proces1");
        lista.add("proces2");
        lista.add("proces3");
        List<MiClase> objs = this.mlRepository
                .findByIdAndValidatedAndProcessIn("cualquierId", 1, lista);
        if (objs.size() == 3) { // Está todo ok
```

Gracias!

Comment: En la [documentación oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) puedes ver cómo se pueden usar y combinar palabras clave que definen la búsqueda. Te iva a poner una respuesta, pero ya lo has resuelto :-)

Comment: Una cosilla, ¿ sabes si Springboot va a lanzar las consultas a la base de datos por cada elemento en el array o sólo se lanza 1 consulta a la BD ?, Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Creo que hace una única consulta, algo como  `where  process_id in (1,2,34...);`